# Removing everything before a repeated character in R

Tags: r, dataframe, path

I have column where it states the path of a file in each row:

```
/fire/A/ega/vol1/XDFG00001004213/exomes100/filename
/fire/A/ega/vol1/XDFG00001004213/exomes100/filename
/fire/A/ega/vol1/XDFG00001006815/exomes100/filename
/fire/A/ega/vol1/XDFG00001006816/exomes100/filename
/fire/A/ega/vol1/XDFG00001006817/exomes100/filename
/fire/A/ega/vol1/XDFG00001006818/exomes100/filename
XDFG00001004043/exomes100/filename
XDFG00001004043/exomes100/filename
```

I would like to remove everything before `/exomes100/*` so it would look like:

```
/exomes100/filename
/exomes100/filename
/exomes100/filename
/exomes100/filename
/exomes100/filename
/exomes100/filename
/exomes100/filename
/exomes100/filename
```

I have tried using `sub`, but I can't find the right combination of characters for the `XDFG000*` as the number changes in every row.

Do you know whether there is another function, or the right combination of characters in order to delete that part of the path?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like `sub(".*\\/(exomes.*)$", "\\1", str1)`

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to capture the characters from `exomes` and then in the replacement, use the backreference (`\\1`) of the capture group

```
sub(".*\\/(exomes.*)$", "\\1", str1)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know which character should I use in order to keep only the filename? In other words, to delete everything before the last /
thanks in advance!

Comment: @AinaJené. If you need the `filename`, then use `basename(str1)`